# Is there a Logback Layout that Creates JSON Objects with Message Parameters as Attributes?

Tags: java, json, slf4j, logback, loggly

I want to send log events to Loggly as JSON objects with parameterized string messages. Our project currently has a lot of code that looks like this:

```
String someParameter = "1234";
logger.log("This is a log message with a parameter {}", someParameter);
```

We're currently using Logback as our SLF4J backend, and Logback's [JsonLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback.contrib/logback-json-classic/0.1.1/ch/qos/logback/contrib/json/classic/JsonLayout.java) to serialize our ILogEvent objects into JSON. Consequentially, by they time our log events are shipped to Loggly, they look like this:

```
{
    "message": "This is a log message with a parameter 1234",
    "level": INFO,
    ....
}
```

While this does work, it sends a different `message` string for every value of `someParameter`, which renders Loggly's automatic filters next to useless.

Instead, I'd like to have a Layout that creates JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "This is a log message with a parameter {}",
    "level": INFO,
    "parameters": [
        "1234"
    ]
}
```

This format would allow Loggly to group all log events with the message `This is a log message with a parameter` together, regardless of the value of `someParameter`.

It looks like [Logstash's KV filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.5/filters/kv) does something like this - is there any way to accomplish this task with Logback, short of writing my own layout that performs custom serialization of the ILogEvent object?

Comment: The problem I see with your example is that you do not know where the parameter would be inserted in the message.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings that shouldn't matter, because the parameters are passed to the `log.log(message, param1, param2);` function. As long as order is preserved in the array that's inserted into the JSON object, all is good.

Comment: but your message in the json did not have any placeholders. If that intentional and not a mistake you would not know how to render the correct message.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings added the placeholder to the sample output JSON

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [Mapped Diagnostic Context](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)  to set a stamp for each of those type of log messages that you could then filter on once in loggly.

According to the source of [JsonLayout](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-contrib/blob/master/json/classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/contrib/json/classic/JsonLayout.java#L158) the stamp is stored as a separate value in the JSON.

Comment: Yup, this is what we ended up using to add arbitrary objects to our log messages.

Comment: Can you provide example?

Comment: The developer will have to add and remove the values from MDC, which does not make it elegant

Answer (score 21):

There is a JSON logstash encoder for Logback, [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder)

Answer (score 12):

So for me I was trying to log execution times, I created a pojo called ExecutionTime with name, method, class, duration.

I was then able to create it:

```
ExecutionTime time = new ExecutionTime("Controller Hit", methodName, className, sw.getTotalTimeMillis());
```

For logging I then used:

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
logger.info(append("metric", time), time.toString());
```

Make sure you have:

```
import static net.logstash.logback.marker.Markers.append;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

This will log something like this:

```
{  
   "ts":"2017-02-16T07:41:36.680-08:00",
   "msg":"ExecutionTime [name=Controller Hit, method=setupSession, className=class com.xxx.services.controllers.SessionController, duration=3225]",
   "logger":"com.xxx.services.metrics.ExecutionTimeLogger",
   "level":"INFO",
   "metric":{  
      "name":"Controller Hit",
      "method":"setupSession",
      "className":"class com.xxx.services.controllers.SessionController",
      "duration":3225
   }
}
```

Might be a different set up as I was using logback-spring.xml to output my logs to json:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <property name="PROJECT_ID" value="my_service"/>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>app/logs/${PROJECT_ID}.json.log</File>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <fieldNames>
                <timestamp>ts</timestamp>
                <message>msg</message>
                <thread>[ignore]</thread>
                <levelValue>[ignore]</levelValue>
                <logger>logger</logger>
                <version>[ignore]</version>
            </fieldNames>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
            <FileNamePattern>app/logs/${PROJECT_ID}.json.log.%i</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>20MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.xxx" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: On applying the similar pattern - 
I see the "metrics" data log duplicated. It came as part of message and separate node as "metric"  - same information printed ? Any suggestions please ?

Comment: I could resolve that duplicate issue as follows.
logger.info("TROS Process Update ",append("trosdata",cleanerLogData),cleanerLogData);

now message got value " TROS Proces Update"

Comment: Yeah the second param is the msg ie:
logger.info(append("metric", metricObject), msgString); So you just need to change msgString to something else.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a recently created project that provides a JSON-specific logging API and works with SLF4J:

https://github.com/savoirtech/slf4j-json-logger

Comment: That's a nice little library. I doubt I'll switch existing projects over to it, as it would require a fair bit of work, but I'll definitely keep it in mind for future projects.

Comment: Thank you @MusikPolice - we appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I'm starting a new project now and will try this out. However, I'm not sure if I can configure default fields to include in log (I managed to do that with Logback, but I don't like relying on MDC to output any field, so I would prefer slf4j-json-logger with it's API). The idea is to have a field+value configured in config file, which would end up automatically added to all produced JSON log lines/objects. Is that possible in slf4j-json-logger?

Comment: There is no feature for that now.  Should be relatively easy to accomplish.  Please either post this as an issue on github (here https://github.com/savoirtech/slf4j-json-logger/issues), or contribute a PR!

Comment: The approach is nice and we tried it, but since the log messages of libraries are NOT formatted as JSON it was of no use for us.

Answer (score 1):

Like already answered you'll get a one-dimensional JSON tree with MDC and/or using a Marker with logstash-logback-encoder.

If you are also looking for the following:

- codebooks for definition of logged datatype key and type,
- configuration of log-aggregation tools (like elasticsearch)
- generated Java helper-code for efficient and correct logging

then try a project I've created: [json-log-domain](https://github.com/skjolber/json-log-domain). It defines a simple YAML-format definition from which the above can be generated.

An example helper-code statement would be

```
logger.info(host("localhost").port(8080), "Hello world");
```

while generated markdown would like something like [this](https://gist.github.com/skjolber/b79b5c7e4ae40d50305d8d1c9b0c1f71).

Answer (score 0):

Not a `Layout`, but the format looks "exactly" like the output of Logback's [`JsonEncoder`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/encoders.html#JsonEncoder) (available since Logback 1.3.8/1.4.8):

```json
{
    ...
    "level": "INFO",
    ...
    "message": "This is a log message with a parameter {}",
    "arguments": [
        "1234"
    ]
    ...
}
```

With the exception of the "parameters" array, which is named `arguments` in the JSON output. See above link for a full example (which unfortunately lacks arguments, but it *does* format messages like this).